# Root explorer does no work

Tags: cyanogenmod, 5.0-lollipop

I installed cm 12 on my nexus 4 and everything seems to work good. But even if I have root enabled and have given root rights to ES Explorer it is not able to mount the root explorer. I want to edit a system file but am not able to.

I have ClockworkMod recovery v6.0.4.7 installed.

Root does work for apps like greenify and lmt launcher but not for ES explorer or 920 texteditor. I tried to modify build.prop in /system/ but am not able to do to rights.

Is there another way I can edit build.prop?

Comment: Did you enable root explorer in settings of es explorer?

Comment: Never ever edit build.prop. It can result in major problems including boot loops, application crashes and even bricks.

Comment: Well, there is [Build Prop Editor](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.jrummy.apps.build.prop.editor) on Play Store, but the fact that the root isn't working on some apps is definitely strange. Have you confirmed if they are blocked on SuperUser app?

Comment: I edited build.prop to remove the navigationbar and use lmt launcher instead to free up screen real estate. This has not caused any problems so far and I have done this sense 4.1. It seems that when I updated to cm12 i need to reinstall apps otherwise some do not work properly. When I reinstalled ES explorer it works as normal.